# Laravel 5.6 consulta whereNotExist

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una practica donde se deben agregar autos a una aseguradora y poder dar de alta sus seguros, y estoy intentando hacer una consulta que, al momento de selecionar una aseguradora de una lista, me regrese todos los vehiculos que no esten en esa aseguradora (incluyendo los que estan en otras), pero al correrla no me devuelve nada.

Esta seria la funcion en el controlador:

```
public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){
            $aseguradora = 2;
            $datos = \DB::table('crlo_vehiculos')
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                $aseguradora = 2;
                $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados')
                      ->whereRaw('crlo_veh_asegurados.id_aseguradora', '=', $aseguradora);
            })
            ->get();
            return $datos;
            }
```

Las tablas serian:

aseguradoras

```
------------------------------------
| id_aseguradora | nom | direccion |
------------------------------------
```

vehiculos

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id_vehiculo | marca | modelo | ano | tipo | color | serial |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

veh_asegurados

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id_aseg | id_vehiculo | id_aseguradora | id_vigencia |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Soy nuevo en esto de laravel, asi que aun no entiendo bien como estructurar la consulta.

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Un paso para poder avanzar y ayudarte sería preguntarte, cómo harías esa consulta en SQL puro? Si ya la tienes puedes colocarla y el resto es traducirla

Comment: Intente hacerla asi : `select * from 'crlo_vehiculos' where not exists (select 1 from 'crlo_veh_asegurados' where  crlo_veh_asegurados.id_aseguradora = 1)` pero no devuelve nada

Comment: Esta consulta funciona: `SELECT * FROM crlo_vehiculos WHERE id_vehiculo NOT IN (SELECT id_vehiculo FROM crlo_veh_asegurados WHERE id_aseguradora = 2)` pero no se como traducirla

Comment: te propongo esta consulta dime si funciona $data = DB::table('crlo_vehiculos')
   ->select('*')
   ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query){
  $query->DB::table('crlo_veh_asegurados')
  ->select('id_vehiculo')
  where('id_aseguradora', 2)
})->get();

Comment: Ya tengo la consulta y ya funciona, igual muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero ahora tengo otro problema. Tengo la funcion: `public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){
   $aseguradora = $request -> input ('sel_as');
    $datos = \DB::table ('crlo_vehiculos') 
      ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query) {
       $as = $aseguradora;
              $query->select('id_vehiculo')
              ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados')
              ->where('id_aseguradora', '=', $as);
      })->get();
      return $datos;
    }` pero me dice "Undefined variable: aseguradora"

Comment: Hola @CarlosRobertoLunaOchoa, para resolver tu último error sólo coloca un `use` después de tu función callback ya que esta función no conoce la variable ya que está afuera de su closure, es decir, lo siguiente: `public function mostrarVehNAs(Request $request){ 
     $aseguradora = $request -> input ('sel_as'); 
     $datos = \DB::table ('crlo_vehiculos') ->whereNotIn('id_vehiculo', function($query) use($aseguradora){ 
      $as = $aseguradora; 
   $query->select('id_vehiculo') ->from('crlo_veh_asegurados') ->where('id_aseguradora', '=', $as);
  })->get(); 
  return $datos; 
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Probaste usando el método `whereNotIn` de las [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)?

```
$aseguradora_id = 2;
$veh_asegurados = DB::table('veh_asegurados')
                    ->whereNotIn('id_aseguradora', [$aseguradora_id])
                    ->get();
```

Creo que el codigo anterior es lo que estás necesitando pero si lo que necesitas es los vehiculos de la tabla `vehiculos` podrías obtener los ids de los vehículos para obtener la info usando el método `whereIn`

```
$aseguradora_id = 2;
$veh_asegurados_ids = DB::table('veh_asegurados')
                    ->whereNotIn('id_aseguradora', [$aseguradora_id])
                    ->pluck('id_vehiculo');

$vehiculos = DB::table('vehiculos')
                    ->whereIn('id', $veh_asegurados_ids)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero de todo es crear el modelo y las relaciones para usar eloquent y seguir la arquitectura que propone Laravel. Olvídate de usar el helper DB::table() y los Raw, dado que están pensados para casos mas puntuales y complejos.

Primero crea tu clase para crlo_vehiculos (la llamaremos CrloVehiculo):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CrloVehiculo extends Model
{
    //use SoftDeletes;

    //protected $dates = [ 'deleted_at' ];

    protected $table = 'crlo_vehiculos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'otro_campo',
    ];
}
```

Ahora dentro de los modelos crearemos las relación (previamente habremos creado el modelo para `crlo_veh_asegurados` con el nombre `CrloVehiculoAsegurado`)

En este caso haremos un 1 a 1 en CrloVehiculoAsegurado

```
public function vehiculo(){
        return $this->hasOne(CrloVehiculo::class, 'id', 'id_vehiculo');
    }
```

y su correspondiente en CrloVehiculo

```
public function aseguradora()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CrloVehiculoAsegurado::class, 'id_vehiculo', 'id');
}
```

Si tienes todas las relaciones es simple, solo necesitas meter una funciona para filtrar en el with o usar whereHas si lo que quieres es filtar

```
 public function mostrarVehNAs(){
        $aseguradora = 2;
        return  CrloVehiculo::whereHas('aseguradora' => function($query) use ($aseguradora){
            $query->where('id_aseguradora', $aseguradora);  // Subquery
        })->get();
    }
```